# How to correctly use non-clustered index to speed up querying in stored procedure

Tags: sql, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I'm preparing a stored procedure to join tables and filter out useful rows. To help the querying, I create an non-clustered index on two columns of table A and then drop it in this sp. It works very well. Since multiple users can call this sp, this index would be created multiple times, which may cause errors. Then I directly added this index into table A as permanent index. But it didn't work at all. This table does not have a primary key, and it may be the reason; then I assigned primary key to column "Id" (not the two columns I used). Then by adding the non-clustered index as permanent index, it worked, but not as good as creating inside the sp. Cannot figure out what's the root cause. Please give me some hint on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Give us a hint as to what you are dealing with and perhaps we can offer you a hint.

Comment: I am working on Microsoft SQL server. You mean the problem itself?

Comment: In oracle, if a procedure forks into multiple processes you can declare it with ```PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS ``` not sure in SQL Server, or if this is even your issue.  You have posted no code or information that would support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Alex. The code is quite long and not sure which part is ok to post here and how to make is more specific. Regardless of the query, for that sp, if I create the non-cluster index inside (did not change anything else), it took a few sec. If I added primary key and non cluster index within the sql table, it took a few min, if I did noting, it took longer.As to the code of creating, adding and dropping index, I google them and they are pretty standard.